# Trouble getting Rails app to be visible on endpoint with GKE Autopilot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

The problem, the load balancer endpoint hangs and doesn't produce any logs that I can find.

Chrome displays:
This site can’t be reached 35.213.138.112
took too long to respond.

I've been stuck on this for 6 hours and I've been struggling to find relevant documentation on Kubernetes and Ruby on Rails. I assume the problem is something simple and todo with my Kubernetes config..

My docker file:

```
FROM ruby:2.6.8
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y nodejs npm postgresql-client
RUN npm install --global yarn
WORKDIR /src/app
COPY Gemfile ./
ADD . /src/app
Copy vendor/gems/* /src/app/vender/gems/
ENV RAILS_ENV production
RUN bundle install --deployment --without development test

# ENV RAILS_ENV production
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile

# Start the main process.
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

My deployment config:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels: 
    name: "test-2"
  name: "test-2"
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "test-2"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "test-2"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "test1-sha256-1"
        image: "gcr.io/path-to-image"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
          protocol: TCP
        env:
          - name: PORT
            value: "3000"
          - name: RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES
            value: "true"
      serviceAccountName: test-ksa
---
apiVersion: "autoscaling/v2beta1"
kind: "HorizontalPodAutoscaler"
metadata:
  name: "test-2-hsdfsdf"
  namespace: "default"
  labels:
    app: "test-2"
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    kind: "Deployment"
    name: "test-2"
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: "Resource"
    resource:
      name: "cpu"
      targetAverageUtilization: 80
```

My pod log (seems to be working fine):

```
Puma starting in single mode...
* Puma version: 5.5.0 (ruby 2.6.8-p205) ("Zawgyi")
*  Min threads: 5
*  Max threads: 5
*  Environment: production
*          PID: 1
* Listening on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

My load balancer config:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-02T02:39:22Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    name: test-no-nginx
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:externalTrafficPolicy: {}
        f:ports:
          .: {}
          k:{"port":80,"protocol":"TCP"}:
            .: {}
            f:port: {}
            f:protocol: {}
            f:targetPort: {}
        f:selector:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
        f:sessionAffinity: {}
        f:type: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-10-02T02:39:22Z"
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup": {}
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2021-10-02T02:40:05Z"
  name: test-no-nginx-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "83916"
  uid: 9b560670-1f4d-41f7-8301-fd6b5c0e18d2
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.95.123.231
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.95.123.231
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32663
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: test-2
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 35.233.233.11
```

If I add an nginx container to my deployment config and don't set a targetPort for the load balancer I can see "Welcome to nginx!" just fine.

config for nginx container in deployment.yml:

```
containers:
 - name: "nginx-1"
   image: "nginx:latest"
```

Thank you for your time, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting up ingress-nginx with the install command from https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/

An ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-test
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: test
              port:
                number: 80
  ingressClassName: nginx
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  controller: k8s.io/ingress-nginx
```

And a NodePort

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress": true}'
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: test
  type: NodePort
```